# datetime.now(tz) and datetime(year, month, day, tzinfo=tz) don't have same UTC offset

Tags: python, datetime, timezone-offset, pytz

Why are the UTC offsets in the 2 datetimes created in the code below different?  I'm using pytz==2019.1

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

EASTERN = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
dt1 = datetime.now(EASTERN)
dt2 = datetime(2020, 8, 11, 15, 30, tzinfo=EASTERN)
print(f'dt1: {dt1}')
print(f'dt2: {dt2}')
```

results:

> dt1: 2020-08-11 18:35:47.984745-04:00

> dt2: 2020-08-11 15:30:00-04:56

The first one shows an UTC offset of -04:00 which is correct (for this time of year), but the 2nd one is giving an UTC offset of -04:56.

How can I declare a datetime with the 2nd method and get the UTC offset from the first method.

Comment: You are comparing the time of the system (now) to some time that you supplied yourself (2020, 8, 11, 15, 30)

Comment: sidenote: your `pytz` is outdated. recommendation: use [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead of `pytz` to avoid such weird behaviour. read [this blogpost](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/03/pytz-fastest-footgun.html) to get more info why this is the case.

Comment: @MrFuppes, your comment is spot on.  After reading just the first couple paragraphs of the linked blog I understood what was going on.  Can you put it in an answer and I'll mark it as THE answer?

Comment: From the blogpost @MrFuppes shared they actually reference this same issue under `pytz's time zone model`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with the shown code is that `datetime.now(tz)` can handle a `pytz.timezone` as `tz` argument while the default constructor `datetime(y,m,d,...)` cannot. In this case, you have to use the `localize` method of the `timezone`,

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

EASTERN = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
dt1 = datetime.now(EASTERN)
dt2 = EASTERN.localize(datetime(2020, 8, 11, 15, 30))
print(f'dt1: {dt1}')
print(f'dt2: {dt2}')
# prints
# dt1: 2020-08-12 10:07:09.738763-04:00
# dt2: 2020-08-11 15:30:00-04:00
```

[dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) avoids this issue, more info can be found [here](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/03/pytz-fastest-footgun.html). That would make the code work "as it is":

```
from dateutil.tz import gettz

EASTERN = gettz('US/Eastern')
dt1 = datetime.now(EASTERN)
dt2 = datetime(2020, 8, 11, 15, 30, tzinfo=EASTERN)
print(f'dt1: {dt1}')
print(f'dt2: {dt2}')
# prints e.g.
# dt1: 2020-08-12 10:20:07.796811-04:00
# dt2: 2020-08-11 15:30:00-04:00
```

In addition `pytz` is likely to be [deprecated with Python 3.9](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/) as you'll have [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/zoneinfo.html) as part of the standard library for these kinds of jobs.

Answer (score 1):

with regards to `dt1`:

`datetime.now()` will return the `tzinfo` from utc. You can see this if you do the following:

```
>>> repr(EASTERN.fromutc(datetime.now()))
"datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 11, 12, 33, 28, 849873, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)"
```

the `tz.fromutc()` is what `datetime.now()` does behind the scenes.

with regards to `dt2`:

if you check the repr of EASTERN you will see the following:

```
>>> repr(EASTERN)
"<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>"
>>> repr(dt2)
"datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 11, 15, 30, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>)"
```

I'm not very comfortable with timezone differences so I don't want to steer you in the wrong direction, but from what I can tell both of these two options yield the same result:

```
dt2 = datetime(2020, 8, 11, 15, 30, tzinfo=EASTERN)
dt2_eastern_corrected = EASTERN.fromutc(dt2)
dt3 = datetime(2020, 8, 11, 15, 30)
dt3_eastern_corrected = EASTERN.fromutc(dt3

>>> repr(dt2_eastern_corrected)
"datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 11, 11, 30, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)"
>>> repr(dt3_eastern_corrected)
"datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 11, 11, 30, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)"
```

Comment: Maybe I should have been more clear; all I'm saying is that if you follow the breadcrumbs you'll see `datetime._fromtimestamp()` will return ` tz.fromutc(result)` if `tz` is passed into `datetime.now()`.

Comment: actually, the second part of your code (using `pytz.timezone.fromutc`) is quiet interesting, I presume this retrieves the internal timestamp (POSIX) of the datetime object, ignoring the tzinfo?

Comment: I'm not too sure about that part, if that is what `BaseTzInfo.fromutc` does then probably, but from a quick check [you can see](https://github.com/stub42/pytz/blob/master/src/pytz/__init__.py#L225) it does the localization in one step.

Comment: Just realized it is a [wrapper over `datetime.tzinfo`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/datetime.py#L1137). I'm not too sure what the algorithm for `tzinfo.fromutc` but you can read it [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/datetime.py#L2307).

Comment: at least I think my assumption is wrong, it has nothing to do with the POSIX timestamp. If tzinfo of the datetime object passed is None, it calls localize. if tzinfo is set, it gets a bit hard to follow, but it seems the tzinfo is basically just overridden. Not sure I totally get that, though...